# Join sublist in a list in python when the sublists are still items in the big list

Tags: python, list, join

I have a list like this:

```
l = [[1,4], [3,6], [5,4]]
```

I want to join the inner list with ":". I want to have the result as:

```
l = ['1:4', '3:6', '5:4']
```

How can I achieve it with Python?

Comment: What have you tried? See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Any piece of code?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do:

```
final_list = []
for i in l:
    a = str(i[0])+':'+str(i[1])
    final_list.append(a)
print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to achieve this:

```
[':'.join(map(str, x)) for x in l]
```

Comment: @detuvoldo Great!  Feel free to upvote/accept the answer by clicking the green tick on the left if your problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[1,4], [3,6], [5,4]]
fl = []
for x in l:
    fl.append(str(x[0])+':'+str(x[1]))
print(fl) # Final List, also you can do: l = fl
```

But, i think that you want to do dictionaries, if this is true, you have to do:

```
l = [[1,4], [3,6], [5,4]]
fd = {}
for x in l:
    fd[x[0]] = x[1]
print(fd) # Final Dictionary
```

**EXPLANATION:**

```
l = [[1,4], [3,6], [5,4]]              # Your list
fl = []                                # New list (here will be the result)
for x in l:                            # For each item in the list l:
    fl.append(str(x[0])+':'+str(x[1])) # Append the first part [0] of this item with ':' and the second part [1].
print(fl)
```

With Dictionaries:

```
l = [[1,4], [3,6], [5,4]]     # Your list
fd = {}                       # New dictionary
for x in l:                   # For each item in the list l:
    fd[x[0]] = x[1]           # Make a key called with the first part of the item and a value with the second part.
print(fd) # Final Dictionary
```

**Also you can make a dictionary easier:**

```
l = [[1,4], [3,6], [5,4]] 
l = dict(l)                   # Make a dictionary with every sublist of the list (it also works with tuples), the first part of the sublist is the key, and the second the value.
```